# Cannot add record(s); join key of table '....' not in record-set

Tags: ms-access

My problem: Cannot add record(s); join key of table '....' not in record-set.
I am currently working on a database for a school to establish an organized virtual information center that will allow administrators to input/manipulate/update data concerning general information about students. 
I have very little experience with Microsoft Access as I am still learning how to use the program. I have created a form that includes joint tables containing information about the students. My problems is that whenever I try to update the form with new data, I receive the message "Cannot add record(s); join key of table 'Student' not in record-set" and it wont let me input information. How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Could you add sample data, schema information, code?

Comment: If you're using a combo box to select a related item from a linked table, you should not include that table in the record source for the form, just in the control source for the combo box. The combo box will then look up the related item for you.

Comment: Can you show the SQL for the record source used in your form?